# Using NSubstitute to check a single optional argument

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nsubstitute

Is there a way to check a single value passed to an NSubstitute fake, without having to specify the other values?

Image a method with several optional arguments:

```
void myMethod(int a=0, int b=0, int c=0);
```

I'd like to be able to confirm a specific value is passed to one of the parameters, without having to specify the other parameters:

```
fake.Received().myMethod(b: Arg.Is(1));
```

and have this verify calls regardless of whether **a** or **b** are passed.

This works:

```
fake.Received().myMethod(a: Arg.Any<int>(), b: Arg.Is(1), c: Arg.Any<int>())
```

but is not very readable, since the non-relevant arguments clutter the test, and will break if another argument is added to `method`.

However, this will ignore method calls that do not pass default values to the optional parameters:

```
NSubstitute.Exceptions.ReceivedCallsException : Expected to receive a call matching:
myMethod(0, 1, 0)
Actually received no matching calls.
Received 1 non-matching call (non-matching arguments indicated with '*' characters):
myMethod(*2*, 1, 0)
```

And using `ReceivedWithAnyArgs` will cause the Arg.Is() to be ignored, creating a test that passes regardless of the value of **b**.

Finally, I tried arranging the fake to capture the value:

```
fake.method(b: Arg.Do<int>(i => captureValue = i));
```

But this is not hit unless the signature is matched exactly.  I'm looking for a way to test a single value without having to rewrite a large number of tests when an optional parameter is added to a method.

Note: This example uses `int` values, but the same issue occurs with reference types.

And a note to the maintainer: I would expect Arg.Is to override ReceivedWithAnyArgs, if that is a feasable modification.  This would allow creating minimally specified tests.

Comment: NSub doesn't support this sorry. I think you're stuck specifying all the arguments.

Comment: Thanks David.  Is there a fundamental problem doing this, or should I add as a feature request to Github?

Comment: You're welcome to add a feature req. I'm not sure how doable it is, but someone might get a brainwave on how to do it. :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mocking a function with optional parameter with fixed parameter using Nsubstitute in C# returns null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71426035/mocking-a-function-with-optional-parameter-with-fixed-parameter-using-nsubstitut)

Comment: Issue on GitHub https://github.com/nsubstitute/NSubstitute/issues/629#issuecomment-687689933