# Mocking a function with optional parameter with fixed parameter using Nsubstitute in C# returns null

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, nsubstitute

I have been trying to mock a function that included optional parameters with fixed parameters but every time I am getting a null value
here is my function defined in interface which I want to mock:

```
List<object> GetEntitiesByIDs(List<long> ids, bool includeStatuses = false, bool includeRounds = false, bool includeSample = false);
```

Method calling this function:

```
        public object ExportSpecimens(List<long> ids)
        {
            var specimens = Repo.GetEntitiesByIDs(ids, includeSample: true);
        }
```

Here is my test method:

```
        public void ExportSpecimens_ValidData_Success()
        {
             var _repo = Substitute.For<IRepo>();
            _repo.GetEntitiesByIDs(Arg.Any<List<long>>(), includeSample: Arg.Any<bool>()).Returns(_specimens);

        }
```

whenever I am hitting the function in **ExportSpecimens** I am getting **null** value.
I also tried to include all the parameters in both the test and main function but it didn't work.
but I have noticed some ambiguity after hitting the function **GetEntitiesByIDs** first time in **ExportSpecimens** I am getting **null** value and then I hit it again by scrolling up the debugger point or in immediate windows I am getting correct input.

I am not able to understand how can I mock this function without any issue?

Comment: Why don't you mock all three booleans?

Comment: I have tried this @palleDue but I am still getting null value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not able to find anything in which I can have a better understanding of the solution to my question. However, for now, to move my work forward I have come to a workaround in which I have created an overloaded function with the fixed parameters which I am able to mock successfully.

For example:

I want to mock this function:

```
List<object> GetEntitiesByIDs(List<long> ids, bool includeStatuses = false, bool includeRounds = false, bool includeSample = false);
```

Instead of directly mocking it I have created an another function which calling this main function:

```
List<object> GetEntitiesByIDs(bool includeSample, List<long> ids){
   GetEntitiesByIDs(ids, includeSample: includeSample)
}
```

and it worked like a charm!

Comment: Similar suggestion from NSubstitute author https://github.com/nsubstitute/NSubstitute/issues/629#issuecomment-687689933